# Python: extract numbers based on letters

Tags: python, regex, numbers, extract

I have a string ("1x5y") from which I want to extract the numbers, but I want to extract those numbers based on the letter. From my string I want to end up with x = 1 and y = 5.
Also, either x or y may or may not be present in the string, but at least one of them will always be present (and only once, not more than once).
I managed to do this with regex and a few "if"s, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you

EDIT: here is what I have

```
delta = "2y"
if ("x" in delta) and ("y" in delta):
    x = re.findall('\d+',str(re.findall('\d+x',delta)))
    y = re.findall('\d+',str(re.findall('\d+y',delta)))
elif ("x" in delta) and ("y" not in delta):
    x = re.findall('\d+',str(re.findall('\d+x',delta)))
elif ("x" not in delta) and ("y" in delta):
    y = re.findall('\d+',str(re.findall('\d+y',delta)))
else:
    x = y = 0
```

Comment: You said you've managed to do this with an approach.  Can you post this approach so we can know what you've tried?  Also important, do you they always appear *in that order*? "Number -> Letter"

Comment: I have added what  I did; no, they don't always show in the same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic and naive regex to solve this is `(\d+)([a-zA-Z])`, and there's no need for any `if`s. The capturing groups will take care for "associating" each number to the letter on the right of it.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)([a-zA-Z])')
for string in ['1x5y', '1x', '5y', '111x2y333z']:
    print(string)
    for number, letter in regex.findall(string):
        print(number, letter)
    print()
```

Outputs

```
1x5y
1 x
5 y

1x
1 x

5y
5 y

111x2y333z
111 x
2 y
333 z
```

Comment: [`[A-z]`, will match `[ \ ] ^ _ `](http://www.asciitable.com/) in addition to the letters.  Better to use `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @user3483203 Noted

Comment: Thank you, this is elegant enough and simple enough too!

Answer (score 0):

You can precompile the regex and assign with `findall()`

```
import re

s = "1x5y"
p = re.compile(r'(\d+)x(\d+)y')
(x, y) = re.findall(p, s)[0]
```

Comment: "either x or y may or may not be present in the string"

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)